# 2 way ssl configuration at salesforce side

Tags: authentication, ssl

Do we need to upload any server certificate or any other configuration while sending api request in 2 way ssl?

Here i wanted to understand that what all i need to do to setup mutual SSL/TLS where salesforce act as client.

Comment: Query got resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In salesforce we don't need to upload any server certificate, it automatically taken care by salesforce. salesforce only need to send self signed/CA signed certificate while communicating to external server.